# Проблема с перегрузкой в c#

Tags: c#

Делал гибкий класс, но в итоге С# не позволяет мне перегрузить операторы. Самое главное, что это два разных метода(возвращает другой тип), но всё равно жалуется. Как это починить?

Ошибка:

```
Notebook.cs(130,23): error CS0111: A member `Engine.Person.getName()' is already defined. Rename this member or use different parameter types
Notebook.cs(120,27): (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
```

```
public NamePerson getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(NamePerson name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public string getName()
{
    return this.name.ToString();
}

public void setName(string name)
{
    this.name.parseString(name);
}
```

Comment: В C# не может быть методов с одинаковыми именами и одинаковыми параметрами, если имя одно, но разные входные параметры, то это да, перегрузка, если имя и параметры одинаковые, но разные выходные параметры, то это не перегрузка, это в C# выдаст конфликт. Для разных выходных данных существует так называемые [Generic методы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods), с помощью которых вы устанавливаете необходимый выходной тип.

Comment: допустим есть код `var p = new Person(); var name = p.getName();` какой из ваших методов тут вызывается и почему?

Comment: ну и если уж говорить о документации, то [`Тип возврата метода не является частью сигнатуры метода в целях перегрузки метода.`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods). То есть с точки зрения компилятора сигнатуры ваших методов совпадают. Потому и ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за разъяснение от EvgeniyZ и tym32167.

Пришлось решить проблему так:

```
public NamePerson getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public void setName(NamePerson name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public string getStringName()
{
    return this.name.ToString();
}

public void setStringName(string name)
{
    this.name.parseString(name);
}
```

Comment: Не знаю, зачем так извращаться, но ваш код, можно преобразовать в свойство.

`public string Name { get => NamePerson.name; set => NamePerson.name = value; }

public NamePerson NamePerson { get;set;}`

Что-то вроде этого...

А для класса NamePerson, можно вообще переопределить ToString как мне кажется.
И еще в C# предпочтителен CamelCase.
Всего доброго, хорошего дня.